# clean all '\n' from the string - php

Tags: php, str-replace

I have database with comments that have a lot of '\n' I build a function that cleans all comments from '\n' (at the view side). It works fine but there still some users that use \n and my function cant clean it. the strange thing is if I copy their comment from the DB and past it in my site, my function works well and clean '\n'. If I edit my comment at the DB and past user's comment the function didn't works. I don't know what to do, I tried use "mysql replace" in the select query but it didn't work too. another strange thing that when I use select replace in phpMyAdmin it works. please help me..

my function:

```
function cleanComments($text){

    return stripslashes(str_replace("\\n", ". ",htmlspecialchars($text)));
}
```

my sql query:

```
SELECT REPLACE(comment_text, '\\n', '.'),date...
```

anyone have idea how clean \n (string) from the comments without change them in the DB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows, a newline is `\r\n`. Since most of your users are probably on Windows, this would explain why just removing `\n` is insufficient.

Now, are these actual newlines you're trying to remove, or literal "backslash-n"? If it's an actual newline, then you should do something like:

```
str_replace(["\n","\r"],"",$text);
```

If it's a literal, then double up those backslashes.

Comment: it literal I see comments with \n. what you mean double up backslashes? like.. \\n?

Comment: what I was confused about is that if you do `$text = json_encode($text)` before and get `\n` and `\t` in your strings you should also try using single quoutes, because when I was trying to find `"\n"` what it actually was doing is trying to find newline but there wasn't new line in string. Be careful.

Answer (score 2):

you must use `\n` ,not `\\n`

```
function cleanComments($text){

    return stripslashes(str_replace("\n", ". ",htmlspecialchars($text)));
}
```

this is  because `"\n"` means new line and `"\\n"` means `"\n"` string;
example :

`echo "\n";`

result : a new line

`echo "\\n";`

result : \n

Comment: because `"\n"` means new line , `"\\n"` means a string : `"\n"`;  <br/>

`echo "\n";` result : a new line  <br/>

`echo "\\n";` result : \n<br/>

Comment: I want remove string '\n' from my comments. I have comments with a lot of "\n"